# Image and label inside a button update on click event wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Having a `StackPanel` inside a Button `buttonPlay` to make it rich content like

```
<Button Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="222,72,0,0" Name="buttonPlay" Click="buttonPlay_Click">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="play.jpg" Height="20" Width="27" />
    <Label Padding="4" Height="27" Width="55" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Times New Roman"> Play</Label>
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

I would like the text inside the label and the image to change when I click the button, to do so inside `buttonPlay_Click` event I have and if else condition, However I do not know how to change the label nor image of it.

```
private void buttonPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (buttonPlay.Content.ToString()  == "Play")
    {
        //....some actions
        buttonPlay.Content = "Stop";
    }
    else
    {
        //.....some other actions
        buttonPlay.Content = "Play";
    }
}
```

How to update label and image according to click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your `Label` and your `Image` a name. Like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="hh">
    <Image  Height="20" Width="27" Name="img" Source="play.jpg" />
    <Label Padding="4" Height="27" Width="55" Name="lbl" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Times New Roman">Play</Label>
</StackPanel>

private void buttonPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (lbl.Content.ToString() == "Play")
     {
         //....some actions
         lbl.Content = "Stop";
         BitmapImage btm = new BitmapImage();
         btm.BeginInit();
         btm.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/stop.png");
         btm.EndInit();
         img.Source = btm;
     }
     else
     {
         //.....some other actions
         lbl.Content = "Play";
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you want image and label both updated in if condition?

Comment: To Setting WPF image source in code you should use `BitmapImage ` I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Set your image source like this:`btm.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/stop.png");` check my updated answer.

Comment: Well, Do not know how to pick the answer As I used advices by you and @kailanjian

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to set names for the child controls such as `buttonPlayImage` and `buttonPlayLabel`, then you can access their properties with the `.` operator.

```
private void buttonPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (buttonPlayLabel.Content == "Play")
    {
        buttonPlayLabel.Content = "Stop";

        buttonPlayImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("stop.png"));
    }
    else
    {
        //other actions
    }
}
```

And for names:

```
<Image Name="buttonPlayImage" ... />
<Label Name="buttonPlayLabel" ... >Play</Label>
```

Comment: I tried `buttonPlayImage.Source = "stop.png"` but I am getting `Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'`

Comment: I guess I am missing something I am getting `Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.BitmapImage(System.Uri)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: Updated again, as you might be able to tell, images are not my strong point, hehe.

Comment: make sure it is where your executable is .../Visual Studio/Projects/ProjectName/bin/debug/ usually

Comment: Well, Do not know how to pick the answer As I used advices by you and @user2946329

Answer (score 0):

You should give names to the Image and Label, then update these two Source and Content. You should not update the button Content as it will replace the all the StackPanel, result Image and Label all disappear.